# Make Logic in Function Recursive

Tags: java, recursion, computer-science, traversal

**Background:** Imagine I have a little Robot. I place this Robot at some Node in a Map (Graph). The Robot can call the giveMeMapCopy() method to get a copy of the whole map that he is sat in. I want to give my little Robot a function by which he can use a breadth first traversal to find the shortest path to the Exit node. Here is an example of such a map:

[image]

I have watched videos on YouTube on how to do a breadth first traversal of a graph, so I have a good idea of what needs to be done. The problem is, I am finding it hard to make my logic recursive. Here is my code:

```
public class Robot
{
    // fields required for traversal
    private Queue<ArrayList<String>> queue;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result;
    private String workingNode;
    private ArrayList<String> routeSoFar;

    private Queue<String> knownShortestPath;

    public Robot() {
        queue = new LinkedList<ArrayList<String>>();
        result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        routeSoFar = new ArrayList<String>();
        knownShortestPath = new LinkedList<String>();
    }

    // Runs when Robot has reached a node.
    public void enterNodeActions() {
        knownShortestPath = determineIdealPath();
    }

    // Runs to determine where to go next
    public String chooseNextNode() {
        if(!knownShortestPath.isEmpty())
        {
            // TODO: Need to go through the 
        }
    }

    public LinkedList<String> determineIdealPath()
    {
        try {
            // Get the map
            Map m = giveMeMapCopy();

            // Get all entry nodes of map
            Set<String> entryNodes = m.getEntryNodes();

            /*
             * Loop through all Entry nodes, and find out where we are.
             * Set that as current working node.
             */
            for (String n : entryNodes) {
                if(n == getMyLocation())
                {
                    workingNode = n;
                }
            }

            // All enighbours of working node.
            Set<String> neighboursNames = getNeighboursNames(workingNode);

            /*
             * For each neighbour, construct a path from working node to the neighbour node
             * And add path to Queue and Result (if not already present).
             */
            for(String node : neighboursNames)
            {
                if(!node.equals(getMyLocation()))
                {
                    ArrayList<String> route = new ArrayList<String>();
                    route.add(getMyLocation());
                    route.add(node);
                    if(!containsRoute(result, route))
                    {
                        if(!containsRoute(queue, route))
                        {
                            queue.add(route);                           
                        }
                        result.add(route);
                    }
                }
            }       
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Where I want the recursion to happen is after I have gone through all neighbours of the Entry node [ A ], I want to move to the next [ B ] and do the same for that, i.e. go through each of its neighbours (ignoring A, cause it is already present in Result list) and add them to the Queue and Result lists.

I hope the problem is clear, if not please let me know, and I'll try to clarify anything is not clear.

Comment: better than watching videos, you should also read some intriduction to recursive programming

Comment: If you have problems formulating a recursion, then why don't you try the iterative version with a queue?

Comment: I wanted to learn the neat way of achieving the aim. My Robot will be doing same thing at every node it arrives to, hence why I thought recursion would be best.

Comment: 1. The "neat way" is not the best way 2. Doing the same thing is what iteration is for

Comment: Thanks I think you're right and I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breadth-first search is typically done **without** recursion as it is based on a queue (of partial path in your case). Depth-first search on the other hand is based on a stack, wich can be implemented quite naturally using the call-stack of a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, what you want is to implement [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or something similar to find the shortest path between a source and destination in a graph.

You can find such implementation in Java [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html). Just set all the weights at `1`.